# Java 2D Shading / Filling

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, java-2d

I have created a "blob" from Bezier curves (screenshot below) and would now like to shade it in such a way that it appears pseudo-3D, with darker shading on all "left" edges and lighter on all "right" edges, and perhaps pure white "light spots" on the surface itself.  For example: I'd be interested in how to achieve the shading used in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLnl9xmH8kg).

- Can anyone recommend a good way to achieve this?  I am guessing that standard Graphics2D.fill and setPaint methods may not be sophisticated enough.
- Also, can anyone recommend some good resources (preferrably free / online) for learning more on this?

**EDIT**

Some additional information: To achieve the flat fill effect below I'm creating an `Area` object and am adding the individual `Ellipse2D` `Shape`s to it using `add(new Area(ellipse))` and then finally adding the central polygon area to avoid leaving a white space in the middle.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bc8081cbf2.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bc8081cbf2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPhone apps have access to [OpenGL-ES](http://www.mobileorchard.com/getting-started-with-opengl-es-20-on-the-iphone-3gs/) which allows significant latitude in shading and rendering what is basically a coloured iso-surface with emissive lighting. Java2d will definitely not be sophisticated enough unless you are willing to write a whole software 3d library for it.

Mixing 2d and 3d is also [possible](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/campbell/archive/2006/10/easy_2d3d_mixin.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'm still fairly new to graphics so will probably steer clear of 3D graphics / Open GL for the moment.  Maybe I can cheat by defining a Stroke that applies shading to the edges of the blob.  Not sure if I could change the shading colour depending on the current direction of the path being stroked though.

Answer (score 1):

I used a custom [RadialGradientPaint](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code#GradientImage) in this [kineic model](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel) to get a pseudo-3D effect. I believe a more general [implementation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RadialGradientPaint.html) is available in Java 6.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like Java 6's RadialGradientPaint only shades in a circular fashion but perhaps I can implement my own using this code as a starting point.

Comment: I was thinking you might shade the largest inscribed circle of each ellipse, using alpha to "feather" the edges.